# Your thoughts on mixing non-geometric type with geometric symbol

Tags: logo, typography, icon, sans-serif, serif

I'm working on a logo right now (symbol + wordmark) and I'm trying to decide on a typeface. The symbol is very geometric with straight, angular lines. The typeface I'm leaning towards is a geometric sans serif, which seems like the obvious choice. However, I'm wondering how wrong it would be if I combined a serif, or a flared "semi-serif" type with this very geometric symbol.

Unfortunately I can't show you the design I'm working on (downvote me if you must). But instead I'm attaching something similar I just noticed on Brand New. See how they have combined a serif typeface with a very geometric symbol?

If you have seen any examples of this combination, or read any posts about this topic, please link or post here.

Thank you!

Ash
[image]

Comment: i'm mainly disturbed by the fact that the left image is not a grommet, it's a washer :P

Comment: There are *no* rules.